# For all but finitely many $n \in \mathbb N$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, notation, definition

In my book I have the following theorem:

> A sequence $\langle a_n \rangle$ converges to a real number $A$ if and only if every neighborhood of $A$ contains $a_n$ for all but finitely many $n \in \mathbb N$.

Can anyone clarify what the phrase, "All but finitely many", means?

Comment: It just means that finitely many of the $a_n$ might not be in $A$, but all the rest are. This is equivalent to saying that all of them from some point onwards are in $A$.

Comment: So at some $n$, every neighborhood of $A$ will contain $a_n$?

Comment: The finite number of n depends on the neighborhood you choose. You cant say at some n every neighborhood of A will contain $a_n$.

Comment: Compare this with the usual definition for convergence you will see the connection

Comment: The finitely many that **aren't** in the neighbourhood depends on the chosen neighbourhood, and will typically increase as the size of the neighbourhood shrinks. Note that what you are asked to prove is a very mild rewording of the usual definition of convergence.

Comment: So the phrase just means that there can be finitely many $a_n$ NOT in the neighborhood as long as there are infinitely many in the neighborhood? Correct me if this sounds wrong.

Comment: @Stefan Yes that is correct

Comment: http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Almost_always

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be a sequence, and let $S$ be a set. The assertion that $S$ contains $a_n$ for all but finitely many $n\in\Bbb N$ means that the set $\{n\in\Bbb N:a_n\notin S\}$ is finite: there are only finitely many indices $n$ such that $a_n$ is **not** in $S$. Note that zero is finite: it’s quite possible that $a_n\in S$ for **every** $n\in\Bbb N$.

The key observation, already mentioned in the comments, is that if $\{n\in\Bbb N:a_n\notin S\}$ is finite, either it is empty, or it’s non-empty, in which case it has a largest element. If it’s empty, then $a_n\in S$ for all $n\ge 0$. If it has a largest element, say $m$, then $a_n\in S$ for all $n\ge m+1$. In either case a whole ‘tail’ of the sequence is in $S$.

Conversely, if there is some $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $a_n\in S$ for every $n\ge m$, then

$$\{n\in\Bbb N:a_n\notin S\}\subseteq\{n\in\Bbb N:n<m\}\;,$$

which is a finite set, so $S$ contains $a_n$ for all but finitely many $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: Thanks for that Brian. Makes much more sense now.

Comment: @Stefan: Glad to hear it. You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2):

In your sentence, "but" (is not a conjunction, **but** a preposition and) means "except". At first, I didn't know that the word "but" has two meanings and thus I had exactly the same doubt as you.

Notice that the bold word "but" above (is a conjunction and) doesn't have the same meaning as in your sentence.